# Nodejs Cluster: Choose Worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing, web-worker

I use Nodejs Cluster. I got 8 workers. Whenever I go to the application, I get connected to the same worker, (which is normal since the worker can handle multiple clients.)

For testing purposes, I'd like to connect to different workers without having to siege the application. Is there a way to do that?

Ex: Going to mywebsite.com/3 would connect to 3rd worker.

Comment: I don't think it is possible today.  See: [Node.js Clustering - What determines load balancing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184890/node-js-clustering-what-determines-load-balancing)

Comment: I guess it is possible, but it depends on the structure of your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a port-based solution:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();

  return;

}


function app (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello from ' + cluster.worker.id);
}

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
http.createServer(app).listen(8000 + cluster.worker.id);
```

for example, if you wish to connect to 2 worker you use port 8002.

Comment: Why does this work? I would guess, the `http` module manages re-use of the port (because of `cluster` module use), and since the second port is never touched by another worker, it will always stay bound to only the created server?